# How to store data in only 1 node of a redis cluster

Tags: docker-compose, redis, dockerfile, node-redis, redis-cluster

I have a Redis cluster with six nodes, and currently, Redis is using hashing to distribute data across all six nodes. However, I want to store all of the data in a single node. I understand that this goes against the basic principle of distributed systems, which is to distribute the load and ensure redundancy. However, there are specific use cases where storing all data in a single node is necessary, and I am facing one such use case.

My question is, how can I achieve this? Is there a way to configure Redis to store all data in one node? Can I simply allocate all the slots to just one node, or is there a more complex process involved?

Comment: Why don't you just use a single Redis instance?

Comment: Hi, I need a redis cluster, this is a must requirement. Can we create a cluster with one instance or a cluster in which all the slots will be assigned to one master node ?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can make sure your keys are all on the same node to to use hashtags.

No. Not the Twitter thing. #facts. This:

```bash
redis.local>SET foo:{1234} alfa
redis.local>SET bar:{1234} bravo
redis.local>SET baz:{1234} charlie
```

The value in the curly braces is the hashtag. The hashtag, if present, is used to determine the hashslot instead of the the key name itself.

So, give all your keys the same hashtag and they'll all get the same hashslot and they'll all be on the same shard.

Comment: Hi, thankyou for the response, but I can't use tags because I can't change that code i have a docker-compose file in which I am setting up this redis cluster is there any way I can get this functionaly using docker-compose file ?